# Axiom of Archimedes implication

Tags: real-analysis

How does "for any positive real number $x > 0$ there exists a natural number $n$ such that $x \geq 1/n$" imply "if $|x| \leq 1/n$ for every natural number $n$, then $x = 0$"?

Is it the contrapositive?

Comment: This is equivalent to the nested interval property - which, in itself, is equivalent to the Axiom of Completeness ("Every nonempty set of real numbers with an upper bound has a least upper bound.")! One can perhaps use the statement as is and consider $\frac{1}{|x|} \geq n$...

Comment: We are given that "for every $x>0$ there is an $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $x\ge1/n$". Can you verify that this statement is equivalent to the slightly stronger statement "for every $x>0$ there is an $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $x\color{red}{>}1/n$"? Now, this latter statement can be written in logical form as
$$
(\forall x)(x>0\implies (\exists n\in\mathbb N)(x>1/n)) \, ,
$$
and taking the contrapositive, this becomes
$$
(\forall x)((\forall n\in\mathbb N)(x\le1/n)\implies x\le 0) \, .
$$
Now apply the above with $|x|$ in place of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, is involves contraposition. The contraposition of $A \rightarrow B$ is $\neg B \rightarrow A$.

The Archimedean property is an implication:

*If* $x$ is a positive real, *then* there exists a natural number $n$ such that $x \geq \frac{1}{n}$.

The contraposition is then

*If* there is no natural number $n$ such that $x \geq \frac{1}{n}, *then* $x$ is not a positive real.

The statement “there is no natural number $n$ such that $x \geq \frac{1}{n}$” is equivalent to "for every natural number $n$, $x < \frac{1}{n}$".

But how do we know that $d$ must be $0$? If $x$ is negative, then it is never the case that the absolute value satisfies that $|x| \leq \frac{1}{n}$ for every natural $n$.